# Provide instance without interface using Dagger

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

There is way to provide instance without actual constructor calling.

```
class ModelImpl @Inject constructor(...): Model{}

@Provides
fun model(inst: ModelImpl): Model = inst
```

Is there way to do the same if there is no interface? `Dagger` knows already all dependencies for `ModelImpl`, so it can create an instance.

This gives obviously dependency cycle:

```
@Provides
fun model(inst: ModelImpl): ModelImpl = inst
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use constructor injection Dagger can construct the object for you and you're already using Dagger to create `ModelImpl` to use it as a binding for `Model` in your example!

```
class ModelImpl @Inject constructor(...): Model{}

@Provides
fun model(inst: ModelImpl): Model = inst

// somewhere else...
// both variants would work!
@Inject lateinit var modelImpl : ModelImpl
@Inject lateinit var model : Model
```

The same would work without the interface

```
class ModelImpl @Inject constructor(...)

// somewhere else...
@Inject lateinit var model : ModelImpl
```

If you annotate the constructor then Dagger can create the object for you (if all dependencies can be resolved). This works the same wherever you request the object / dependency,

- as a parameter in a `@Provides` annotated method (as your example)
- as a field injection property (`@Inject lateinit var`)
- as a parameter in another objects constructor
- as a provision method in a component (`fun getFoo() : Foo`)

All of the following would work

```
// foo and bar can both be constructor injected
class Foo @Inject constructor()
class BarImpl @Inject constructor(val foo : Foo) : Bar

@Module
interface BarModule() {
  @Binds  // you should prefer Binds over Provides if you don't need initialization
  // barImpl can be constructor injected, so it can be requested/bound to its interface here
  fun bindBar(bar : BarImpl) : Bar
}

@Component(modules = BarModule::class)
interface BarComponent {
  fun getBar() : Bar // returns barImpl due to binding
}

@Inject lateinit var bar : BarImpl // but we could as well use the implementation directly
@Inject lateinit var bar : Foo // or just foo
```

I recommend you to start with a small example, then compile the project and have a look at the generated code. If something is wrong you'll get errors immediately, while you can play around and try different setups!

Comment: Thanks! That makes it clear. It turns out that `Module` is not even required for providing instances.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to `David Medenjak` anwser. If there is no interface and there is no requirement to group instances into modules, then module could be omitted completely:

```
class Model @Inject constructor(...){
  //...
}

@Component
interface SomeComponent{
  fun model(): Model
}

val model = someComponent.model()
```